# Is there any limitation to the number of nodes in Botpress

Tags: node.js, chatbot

I am making a chat bot using Botpress. The issues is the flow does not gets to next node instead it ends the flow, even when conditions applied or simply flow to next node , both wont let the flow to next node.

i have 16 nodes and 4 of them have conditions to flow to next node.First 3 are working fine 4th ends the flow where as it should go to next node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue sorted in new version of botpress